# What applications of Sith magic have there been?

Tags: star-wars

I just read *Darth Bane: Dynasty of Evil* and it said that Darth Zannah had a mastery of Sith magic. I looked all over the Internet, but couldn't find a description of Sith magic. What kinds of spells can Sith sorcerers perform besides the pitiful showings described on Wookieepedia?

Comment: They can do anything they need to do.  It is a matter of how to get it done.  Figuring that out requires experiments, investigation, and trial and error.

Answer (score 5):

One of the most impressive examples of Sith Magic/Sorcery was the [Ritual](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Ritual_of_Nathema) carried about on [Nathema](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Nathema) by the Sith emperor, stripping the planet of life.

Darth Aneddu was also a notable practitioner, and like many other practitioners, he was skilled in the preserving of his spirit after death, a skill different than the Force Ghost personified by Jedi such as Obi-wan, Yoda, and Anakin. Many of the notable Sith sorcerors used the ritual of [essence transfer](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Transfer_essence).

> Andeddu furthered Muur's studies in dark side healing in an attempt to circumvent death, and developed a technique which allowed his mind to live past his physical demise. Through this skill, Andeddu was able to exert control over his dead body, though his mind remained separated from it. His most coveted ability was that of essence transfer, which potentially was a means of immortality. He preserved the secrets of his abilities within a holocron of his own creation; when the device came into contact with his corpse, the life energy of the individual who placed it there was then sapped, and the Dark Lord was resurrected.
>
> According to Darth Wyyrlok, Andeddu's true power lay not in his corporeal form, but within his mind.
>   ([source](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Darth_Andeddu))

[Darth Zannah](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Darth_Zannah), Bane's apprentice, was also a noted practitioner and was able to resist Bane's attempt at essence transfer. Some of her abilities were ([source](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Darth_Zannah#Force_mastery)):

> "I can use my powers to conjure up your worst nightmares and bring them to life before your eyes. I can drive you mad with fear, shred your sanity, and leave you a raving lunatic for the rest of your life." 
>       ―Zannah, describing the effects of her sorcery
>
> She studied the doctrines of the ancient Sith magician Freedon Nadd and mastered his teachings for a variety of effects—covering herself and others in a false light side aura, driving people insane by showing them their greatest fears, or even simply masking her presence in the Force were all within the scope of her abilities...
>
> Zannah's spell of concealment was so strong that its effects lingered on for years after its use. The decade-old remnants of her concealment charm were so powerful that it violently disrupted the psychometry of Darth Cognus when she attempted to read Caleb's hut...
>
> Among her holdout talents was the conjuring of dark side tendrils—negative Force manifestations that appeared in the form of black mist and were capable of disintegrating flesh and bone on contact.

The [page on Sith magic](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Sith_magic) has a rather long list of notable practitioners over in the sidebar (note that it scrolls). By looking in the "Powers and abilities" section of each person, you can find more information on different uses of Sith magic (also known as Sith sorcery).

Answer (score 3):

While the main Wookieepedia [Sith Magic](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Sith_magic) article does indeed lack a full list,

1. A great list of Sith Magic is on Wookieepedia's [category list](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Category:Sith_magic).
2. [This article](https://starwars-exodus.fandom.com/wiki/Sith_Magic) (sourced from Wookieepedia to an extent) is fairly comprehensive, with a large list of spells. The ones that are more common are:

   ```
   Aura of uneasiness
   Memory rub 
   Summon darkness 
   Summon fear
   Illusion (Sith magic)
   Force blast
   Spell of concealment
   ```